# On apache how do I allow access to only to a single file?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a apache machine which is serving a `.js` file. That file should be the only file that need to seen.

#### Edit:

I have configured to do so in my apache like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:7090>
        ServerAdmin localhost@test.in
        DirectoryIndex test.js
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test
        ServerName test.in
</VirtualHost>


<Location /var/www/test/test.js>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

The site address is `test.in` which points to `test.js` file in `/var/www/test` directory. That is working fine. But I wish when the user tries to hit `test.in/someurl` (which is not available) or some other url than `test.in` need to give an message with `401` error.

How do I do that?

Comment: "points to" is what? A symlink in the filesystem, a redirect, a rewrite?

Comment: @Nils: I have setup my `virtualhost` with the attribute `DocumentRoot` which is pointing to that file.

Comment: I still don`t get it. `DocumentRoot` can point to a directory. Not to a file...

Comment: Maybe @sriram would like to map the URI `/` to the `test.js` resource transparently for the user/client. In that case we can use an `Alias` directive or a `RewriteRule`.

Comment: @Nils: I have edited my question and added the code which I used to serve the file

Answer (score 6):

The [`Location`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) directive matches URIs, not directly related to files on the filesystem. I suggest to use [`Directory`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) and [`Files`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files) instead, like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/test">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    <Files "test.js">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Nope now I cant even able to access the `test.in`. I get `forbidden` error!

Comment: @sriram That was exactly your request if I read correctly. "That file should be the only file that need to seen." So all other files including the default index files should not be accessible, right?

Comment: ya but `test.in` should be given access to the file `test.js`. But now I couldn't be able to do that.

Comment: @gertvdijk `<Files>` can't have directory paths - try `<Files "test.js">` within the `<Directory>` block?

Comment: @ShaneMadden so true! fixed.

Comment: Still this doesn't worked@!

Comment: You **can also use only the `<Files>`** part, especially helpful when putting a special `.htaccess` somewhere in the directory structure opening a single file among otherwise locked files.

Answer (score -1):

You have specifically allowed access to your test.js file, but you need to disallow access to the overlying folder as well.

```
<Location /var/www/test/>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Location>
<Location /var/www/test/test.js>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```